# how to group array objects by using same nested objects value inside aggregate in mongoose nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I need to group all array object and nested objects using given array objects based on same key value inside $project in mongoose aggregate.

Need to group all the title which one have same key value and also need to group nested objects as per appropriate keys. The key value might be dynamic one like "color, size, weight, height, ram, storage, etc,."

```
{ $group: { 
 _id: null, 
 "dynamicFilter": { "$push": '$product' },
 }},
$project: { _id: 0,
    autoFilter: {
            $filter: {
                input: '$dynamicFilter',
                as: 'filterData',
                cond: {

                }
            }
        }
    }}
```

### Note

"$dynamicFilter" has some array object string which one get from collection

### My mongoose collection's sample record (product field array value is stored as string here)

```
_id:ObjectId("5d2f8835d5027d4a5f9b535a") 
product:"[{"title":"COLOR","attribute":[{"label":"Red","isDefaul..."}{"label":"black","isDefaul..."}]}]"

_id:ObjectId("5d2f8835d5027d4a5sdf7654") 
product:"[{"title":"RAM","attribute":[{"label":"8GB","isDefaul..."}]}]"
```

## Expect result

The "title" key value might be dynamic one like "color, size, weight, height, ram, storage, etc,."

```
{
  "autoFilter": [
    {
      "title": "Color",
      "attribute": [
        {
          "label": "Gold"
        },
        {
          "label": "rose"
        },
        {
          "label": "black"
        },
        {
          "label": "blue"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "title": "RAM",
      "attribute": [
        {
          "label": "4GB"
        },
        {
          "label": "3GB"
        },
        {
          "label": "8GB"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "title": "Stroage",
      "attribute": [
        {
          "label": "32GB"
        },
        {
          "label": "64GB"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "title": "size",
      "attribute": [
        {
          "label": "5inch"
        },
        {
          "label": "6inch"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: `autofilter` does not appear to be an **array** in your presented question. Also your stated aggregation pipeline cannot work at all. The `$group` stage only outputs two fields and none of these is called `autofilter` which you claim to be referencing in a later `$project` stage and this is simply not possible. I suggest if you actually have a problem to solve, then you should present an accurate picture of your data and what result you expect to achieve that is actually obtainable from that data sample in the question.

Comment: In short, please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and please actually include actual code attempts rather than claims of code which cannot possibly produce any result. Let alone the claimed result.

Comment: My Mongoose looks like for sample one record
----------------------------------------------
_id:ObjectId("5d2f8835d5027d4a5f9b535a")
product:"[{"title":"COLOR","attribute":[{"label":"Red","isDefaul..."

Comment: There us actually an [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58076371/edit) function that allows you to add new details to your question. That's how you add new information such as documents an code. Not in comments please.

Comment: Yes i have update it now. Could you see my update

Comment: *".. product field array value is stored as string here"* -- The aggregation framework **cannot** do that. There is no method to convert a string in a JSON structure into any form that can be manipulated. You really need to update your data instead. And updating and correcting your data cannot be done using the aggregation framework. Loop the collection and correct it.

Comment: Any alternative option by using same data format without touch schema?